# I am getting 'users' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, variable-declaration

I can't find what's wrong in my code and tried everything. It's my first time working with maps so I'm not sure this is how I get the value of the second key. This is my code:

```
bool DeleteConnection(ServerData &sd, ServerName sn, UserName un){
if(sd.find(sn) == sd.end()){
 return false;
}
else{
  auto search = sd.find(sn);
  if(search != sd.end()) {
   std::set<string> users = search->second;
  }
  const bool is_in = users.find(un) != users.end();
  if(is_in){ //un connected
    users.erase(un);
    sd[sn] = users;
    return true;
  }
  else{ //un not connected
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vlad from Moscow pointed out, once the `if` scope ends, your `users` variable cease to exist, therefore you get the error when you are trying to use it outside of `if` scope. I would rewrite your function to make it more clear:

```
bool DeleteConnection(ServerData &sd, ServerName sn, UserName un)
{
    auto search = sd.find(sn);

    if (search == sd.end())
        return false;

    std::set<string> users = search->second;

    if (users.find(un) == users.end())
        return false;

    users.erase(un);
    sd[sn] = users;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The scope of the object `users` is the sub-statement of the if statement.

```
  if(search != sd.end()) {
   std::set<string> users = search->second;
  }
```

Outside the scope of the if statement the name `users` is undefined.

In fact the function design is wrong. You should rewrite the function body.